# Jmeter: How to get exact response of page

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter so i don't know if am asking a silly question. I am testing the performance of a web application but while testing i notice that there are multiple requests on a page. For e.g. when a user access a page www.xyz.com then there are static content plus there is another request to the server from the same page which is displaying data in a grid (www.xyz/getdata) plus there are js and css files. I want to know if there is way to retrieve all the request of a page.I have already tried the http request sampler with 'retrieve all embedded resources from html file' turned on but when i viewed all the request in view result tree it is displaying 34 requests where as Chrome is displaying 68 requests so i am not sure this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You give us not much information. But I guess, that your web page use AJAX call to retrieve JS, pictures and so on. Jmeter can't get these files because Jmeter don't execute your HTML file like a web browser.

It's possible that you find a plugin for Jmeter or you have to simulate your AJAX calls or you have to change your tool. Please look to XLT from Xceptance [XLT](https://www.xceptance.com/) or phantomjs and derivates or [WPT](http://www.webpagetest.org/).

Comment: your XLT link seems broken. Could you please provide relevant link? Thanks in advance

Comment: The company name is Xceptance, hence the link is https://www.xceptance.com/en/xlt/

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you're trying to simulate a realistic load you need to "tell" JMeter t[o behave  more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser). It includes:

1. HTTP Cookie Manager (in majority of cases it's a must) to deal with cookies and authentication
2. HTTP Cache Manager to represent browser cache
3. HTTP Header Manager with browser's (Chrome in your case) User-Agent string. Some sites vary output for different user agents.
4. You already know about embedded resources.

You can also try recording your test case via JMeter HTTP Test Script recorder, capture additional requests, place them in your test plan, better under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)to avoid getting metrics separately.

If JMeter will be unable to record extra requests, you'll need to capture them via any sniffer tool, the easiest is [HttpFox Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/), the most powerful is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and manually construct missing requests.

In general if your missing resources are totally external it isn't a good idea to load-test them.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it.

You must use Jmeter + Webdriver Sampler + PhantomJS Config. This way:

1) Download and install the [WebDriver Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.4.0.zip) of plugins. Plugin installation is documented [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/).

2) Download and put the [phantomjs executable](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) somewhere on your disk.

3) Create a test plan just like shown on [Webdriver Two minute tutorial](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/), but replace FireFoxConfig with "bzm - PhantomJS Driver Config".

4) On PhantomJS Driver Config, open the PhantomJS tab and set the path to the phantomjs.exe on your disk.

5) On the WebDriver Sampler view, type in the following script:

```
var selenium = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var fileUtils = JavaImporter(org.apache.qpid.util)
var io = JavaImporter(java.io)
var supportUi = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

// set the browser window dimension to fit your needs
var dimension = new selenium.Dimension (4080, 9000);
WDS.browser.size = dimension;
WDS.browser.manage().window().size = dimension;

// put your webpage bellow
WDS.browser.get('http://MYPAGE.com')

// take a screenshot of the page, save it to disk
var screenshot = WDS.browser.getScreenshotAs(selenium.OutputType.FILE)
fileUtils.FileUtils.copy(screenshot, new io.File('C:\\PATH\\TO\\screenshot.png'))    

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can record the session with the Jmeter itself, and you get all the retrieve a webpage is doing:
[Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)